# unix shell script subprocess result

Tags: shell, unix, subprocess

i'm trying to get the result of a sub process. But for now the only result i can have is the log string.
I would like to test the integer result but i don't know how.

```
buildresult=$(xcodebuild -project $projectfile -nodistribute -activetarget -sdk macosx10.5 "PRODUCT_VERSION_NUM=$PRODUCT_VERSION" 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.4' 'ARCHS=$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)' 'DEMO_PREPROCESSOR_FLAG=_FLUX_DEMO_' "PRODUCT_NAME=$PRODUCTS_ITEM-Demo" 'BASEPRODUCT_NAME=null' -configuration Release build)
```

$buildresult contain the  echo log, how to test the result ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exit status of a subprocess is available in the $? variable:

```
buildresult=$(xcodebuild bla bla)
rc=$?
if test $rc -ne 0; then
    echo "NOT OK!"
    exit $rc
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

or

```
buildresult=$(xcodebuild bla bla) || echo "NOT OK"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use $? to find the return code of the last command. This assumes that the command returns a meaningful return code.

```
$ ls 
   :
   :
$ echo $?
0

$ dgdg
dgdg: command not found
$ echo $?
127

$ rm somefilethatdoesnotexist
rm: cannot remove `somefilethatdoesnotexist': No such file or directory
$ echo $?
1
```